# Trying to create a link within a Google Maps InfoWindow which sends a ajax put with particular ID

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, put

I want to send a ajax put request for a particular object associated with the information in an infoWindow.  I'm not sure how to go about this so that each individual Act! button is bound correctly and calling the rails method with the correct ID

```
for (var i in LocationData) {

var p = LocationData[i];
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
bounds.extend(latlng);
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + p[2] + '</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p>Description:  ' + p[3] + ' </p>'+
  '<p>Coins:  ' + p[4] + '</p><button class="actButton">Act!</button>'
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    _id_: p[4]
});
marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    console.log(this);
    $('.actButton').on('click', function() { 
   $.ajax({
 type: "PUT",
   url: '/change_status',
   data: ??
})  
 })

  });
}
```